# how to include php if condition in html

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I have written a php code to convert html content into pdf using mpdf API, now i want to include a php if condition in to that html content how can i do that?
here is my code:

```
$cart_body='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>New Order Placed</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="400" align="left" valign="top">
<a style="font-size:16px">' if(somecondition){ echo "somecontent"; }
else{
echo "somecontent";
}'</a><br />
</body>
</html>';
```

Comment: use dot operator

like 
 
'content' . if(somecondition){  "somecontent"; }
else{"somecontent";
} . 'content'

Comment: Yeah i have Tried , but its not working,

Comment: @NIRANJANS. see my answer for the right syntax for doing that. `condition?"somecontent":"othercontent"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.` operator for concatenation, see example below:

```
$cart_body='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>New Order Placed</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="400" align="left" valign="top">
<a style="font-size:16px">';
if(somecondition){ $cart_body .= "somecontent"; }
else{
$cart_body .= "somecontent";
}

$cart_body .= '</a><br />
</body>
</html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some good reason for storing all your HTML in a variable, one way to conditionally change it like you want is this:

```
$cart_body='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>New Order Placed</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="400" align="left" valign="top">
<a style="font-size:16px">'.
(somecondition?"somecontent":"othercontent")
.'</a><br />
</body>
</html>';
```

It's not pretty, though.

Answer (score 0):

You may use like this

```
<a style="font-size:16px">';
if(somecondition){ $cart_body .= "somecontent"; }
else{
$cart_body .= "somecontent";
}

$cart_body .= '</a><br />
</body>
</html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) method to format/render your template. like this you may put as many as place holders in your templates and then workout your logic in a more readable way and then inject values to the placeholder(s) at very end :)

```
<?php
// preparing the template
$cart_body = <<<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>New Order Placed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="400" align="left" valign="top">
                    <a style="font-size:16px">%s</a><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;

// working out the logic
$basedOnThisCondition = true;
$whatYouWantToInject = ($basedOnThisCondition) ? 'Was true' : 'Was false' ;

// Injecting value to the placeholder (%s for string)
$rendered_cart_body = sprintf($cart_body, $whatYouWantToInject);

// And here is to test the result 
print_r($rendered_cart_body);
```

p.s.

*there were some missing closers in your html template that I have fixed in the above example :)*